# expand table hidden table rows

Tags: javascript, html

I want to expand the hidden row upon clicking on the row above

```js
$(".main").click(function () {
  $(this).next("tr").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr class="row100 body main">
  <td class="cell100 column1" >39</td>
  <td class="cell100 column2" s>900,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row100 body sub" style="display:none;">  
  <td class="cell100 column1" >exa</td>
  <td class="cell100 column2" >lura</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`<tr>`](https://html.com/tags/tr/)

> The `<tr>` element is used to group together `<th>` or `<td>` values into a single row of ***table*** heading or data values. The `<tr>` element may be a direct child of a  element or nested within a parent `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, or `<tbody>` element.

Place `<tr>` inside of `<table>`:

```js
$(".main").click(function () {
  $(this).next("tr").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="row100 body main">
    <td class="cell100 column1" >39</td>
    <td class="cell100 column2" s>900,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row100 body sub" style="display:none;">  
    <td class="cell100 column1" >exa</td>
    <td class="cell100 column2" >lura</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have table tag, include it work

```
$(".main").click(function () {
    $(this).next('tr').show();
});
```

```js
$(".main").click(function () {
    $(this).next('tr').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="row100 body main">
     <td class="cell100 column1" >39</td>
     <td class="cell100 column2" s>900,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row100 body sub" style="display:none;">  
     <td class="cell100 column1" >exa</td>
     <td class="cell100 column2" >lura</td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
```